# How call the function Draw inside Form1_load?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to call the function Draw inside Form_load, what i should do?

I believe that if there is a way to invoke the Draw function the problem will be solved.

````cs
private void Form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
  void desenha(PaintEventArgs paint)
  {

     Pen Pen = new Pen(mainScreen.limiteMesa, 3);

    PointF point1 = new PointF(mesa[0,0], mesa[0,1]);
    PointF point2 = new PointF(mesa[1,0], mesa[1,1]);
    PointF point3 = new PointF(mesa[2,0], mesa[2,1]);
    PointF point4 = new PointF(mesa[3,0], mesa[3,1]);
    PointF[] curvePoints =
    {
      point1,
      point2,
      point3,
      point4
    };

    paint.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pen, curvePoints);

  }

desenha(PaintEventArgs);

}
```c#
````

Comment: i wouldn't do that at form load. just handle the `Paint` event.

Comment: Subscribe to the Form's `Paint` event. In the event handler, call `desenha(e)`. Remove the method from the Load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should've place your code in Form_Paint event

```
private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // your drawing logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw in the `Paint` handler, then call `Invalidate()` to make the form redraw.

Note that `Paint` can be raised at any time (if the system needs to redraw).